# Парсим страницу после авторизации

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Для парсинга использую **jsoup**.
Нужно спарсить с сайта информацию которая находится в блоке `nav1`. И все бы ничего, НО, если зайти на этот сайт как гость, информация в блоке `nav1` будет другой, а мне нужно спарсить информацию в этом блоке, которую видит авторизованный пользователь.
Форма авторизации на сайте следующая:

```
<form class='mess' method='post' action='/login.php'>
Логин:<br /><input type='text' name='nick' maxlength='32' /><br />
Пароль:<br /><input type='password' name='pass' maxlength='32' /><br />
<label><input type='checkbox' name='aut_save' value='1' /> Запомнить меня</label><br />
<input type='submit' value='Войти' />
```

Пытаюсь парсить таким способом:

```
Document doc = null;
           try {
               Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect("http://mobayle.ru/aut.php")
                        .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                        .execute();

                response = Jsoup.connect("http://mobayle.ru/aut.php")
                        .referrer("http://mobayle.ru/index.php")
                        .data("nick", "droid")
                        .data("pass", "password1")
                        .cookies(response.cookies())
                        .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                        .execute();
                doc = Jsoup.connect("http://mobayle.ru/").cookies(response.cookies()).get();

                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Element blockRega = doc.select("div.nav1").first();
                nav2Reg = blockRega.text();
                System.out.println(nav2Reg);
```

В итоге я получаю ту информацию которая доступна для НЕ авторизованных пользователей.
Буду благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

```
Document doc = null;
           try {
               Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect("http://mobayle.ru/aut.php")
                        .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                        .execute();
               response = Jsoup.connect("http://mobayle.ru/login.php")
                       .header("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8")
                       .data("nick", "droid"
                            ,"pass", "qwerty123")
                       .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                       .timeout(30000).execute();


                doc = Jsoup.connect("http://mobayle.ru").cookies(response.cookies()).get();
                Element blockRega = doc.select("div.foot").first();
                nav2Reg = blockRega.text();
                System.out.println(nav2Reg);
                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```